# mysqld crashes every week whenever i use xampp mysql services upto a extent

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I am using ubuntu 16.04 . i installed xampp on it. And whenever a certain limit is crossed, it shows error and says mysqld stops working. and when i open phpmyadmin. its says no socket found and error #2000. and it always get solved when i throughly uninstall xampp and all mysql services. it got solved.but my all mysql data got deleted. so i thought may be it wont occur if i increase the memory my mysql using. but i dont know how to do this. can anybody help me with this?
i have tried everything but it didnot work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We will help with programming problems, which this is not. The question is likely to be deleted as off topic . Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more information

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you install xampp when the aspects of xampp (Apache, MySQL/MariaDB, PHP) already exists (or could be installed) with Ubuntu?